# Как отделить кириллицу от латиницы и несколько своих условий

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

в данный момент я отделяю так:

```
words_a_z = [x for x in words if re.search('[a-z]', x) if
             x.startswith('var') != True and x.endswith('vz') != True and x[3].isnumeric() != True and x[
                 3].isnumeric() != True and x[9] + x[10].isnumeric() != True and x[15] + x[16] + x[
                 17].isnumeric() != True]
```

как это можно упростить?, то что знаки 9-10, а также 15-17 можно сгруппировать я в курсе

просто по хорошему у меня шаблон того, что нужно не пропустить такой:

var1vartz02tzvz000vz

после var цифры 1-6

после tz и vz любые цифры

вот со всеми условиями:

```
words_a_z = [x for x in words if re.search('[a-z]', x) if x.startswith('var') != True and x.endswith('vz') != True and x[3] != [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and x[4:8] != 'vartz' and x[9:10].isnumeric() != True and x[11:14] != 'tzvz' and x[15:17].isnumeric() != True]
```

проще это можно записать?

**UPDATE:**

мне нужно, чтобы в список НЕ попали

```
var1vartz02tzvz000vz
var1vartz04tzvz004vz
var1vartz04tzvz008vz
var1vartz04tzvz010vz
var1vartz04tzvz012vz
var1vartz04tzvz016vz
var1vartz04tzvz020vz
```

var могут быть 1-6

в tz и vz могут быть любые цифры в первом случае две цифры, во втором три цифры

Comment: А в чём задача? Где условия? Вы привели какой-то свой код без объяснения того, что он **должен** делать.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов обновил вопрос

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос

Comment: Запишите полностью условие регуляркой да и  всё. Но для этого нужно чётко его сформулировать сначала, пока не очень понятно всё-равно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут вроде довольно простое же регулярное выражение получается. Просто пишете ваши литералы и перемежаете их нужным количеством `\d` в тех местах, где возможны произвольные цифры:

```
import re

re_exclude = re.compile(r'var\dvartz\d\dtzvz\d\d\dvz')
words = '''var1vartz02tzvz000vz
var1vartz04tzvz004vz
var1vartz04tzvz008vz
var1vartz04tzvz010vz
var1vartz04tzvz012vz
var1vartz04tzvz016vz
var1vartz04tzvz020vz
somethingdifferent'''.split()
print([word for word in words if not re_exclude.match(word)])
```

Вывод:

```
['somethingdifferent']
```